# regular expression for match (sum), (min) of a word in array

Tags: javascript, regex

Script code:

```
var data=[];
data=["Customer","Customer Number(sum)", "Age(min)"];
for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
{
var regExp = /^((?(sum)).)*$/;
var matches = regExp.exec(data[i]);
}
```

I couldn't make the expression. Can any one help me plz.

Comment: Need to match words whether it ends with (min)/(max)/(sum)... Looking javascript regex for this

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `(` or `)` and place the words with pipe inside. And use the anchor `$` after that to make sure it is at the end of the string.

```
var regExp = /^.*\((?:sum|min|max)\)$/;
```